# UICollectionView SelectedBackgroundView Width?

Tags: ios, xamarin, uicollectionview

I have uicollectionview and each cell has a SelectedBackgroundView property with just the background colour like this:

```
        SelectedBackgroundView = new UIView { BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green };
```

How would I set the width of the selectedbackgroundview? I need it to be half the default value.

I have tried:

```
        SelectedBackgroundView.Frame = new CGRect(SelectedBackgroundView.Frame.X, SelectedBackgroundView.Frame.Y, SelectedBackgroundView.Frame.Width / 2, SelectedBackgroundView.Frame.Height / 2);
```

But this just distorts the view

This where I put the code:

```
    [Export ("initWithFrame:")]
    public PhotoCell(CGRect frame) : base(frame)
    {
        //BackgroundView = new UIView { BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear  };
        SelectedBackgroundView = new UIView { BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green };
        this.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(this.SelectedBackgroundView, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, null, NSLayoutAttribute.NoAttribute, 1, this.Bounds.Height / 2));
        imageView = new UIImageView(frame); // set as you want
        ContentView.AddSubview(imageView);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not add constraints?

You can specify the width and height constraints as `NSLayoutConstraints` and then add them to your `UICollectionViewCell` using the `AddConstraint` method. Here's an example in `F#`:

```
 myCell.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(SelectedBackgroundView, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, NSLayoutRelation.Equal,null,NSLayoutAttribute.NoAttribute, 1, myHeightValue))
```

It would be very similar, if not identical in `C#`

Comment: I tried             imageCell.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(imageCell.SelectedBackgroundView, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, null, NSLayoutAttribute.NoAttribute, 1, imageCell.Bounds.Height/2)); And it doesn't do anything

Comment: Where do you put this code? Ideally, you would want this code to be inside the `ImageCell` class itself. Could you post your full code please.

Answer (score 0):

This code solved my problem:

```
        SelectedBackgroundView.Frame = new CGRect(SelectedBackgroundView.Frame.X + 5, SelectedBackgroundView.Frame.Y + 5, SelectedBackgroundView.Frame.Width-10, SelectedBackgroundView.Frame.Height-10);
```